# How to require and use moonscript functions

Tags: lua, moonscript

This looks very simple but has me stumped, I have a function like this:

```
print_stuff = (name) -> name
```

defined in a folder called `pale_moonlight` so it's here: `pale_moonlight/function.moon`. When I try calling it like this:

```
> f = require 'pale_moonlight.function'
> f.print_stuff 'lolo'
```

I get the error below:

```
[string "tmp"]:1: attempt to index global 'f' (a boolean value)
```

What is the proper way to do this? My moonscript version: 0.2.6, lua version: 5.2.3

Comment: http://moonscript.org/reference/api.html

Comment: You don't return a value from your `pale_moonlight.function` module, so `require` returns a `true` for you. Just put a `print_stuff` as the last line of your module to return your function instead.

Answer (score 4):

The last line of your file should be `{ :print_stuff }`. This is MoonScript for: `return { print_stuff = print_stuff }` and allows the function to be accessed through the table that would be returned by `require`.